# parallel hosts TCP connection

Tags: python, mininet

I am a new in python programmer over mininet simulator, I try to create n host that connect to a single server and generate parallel connection flows the only thing I got is

```
for i in n:
    h=netobgect.get("h%s"%i)
    h.cmdPrint("iperf -c 10.0.0.1 ")
```

the problem that there is delay between host 1 and say n/2 will break the meaning of parallel, Is there any one can help me, I was looking for solutions

instead of for loop, just call it serially but i need my code dynamic
use the scheduling command AT but bring problem

Comment: I need to reach to incast problem where all flows are parallel

Answer (score 1):

Run the commands on background with &.

`for i in n:
      h=netobgect.get("h%s"%i)
      h.cmdPrint("iperf -c 10.0.0.1 &")`